# How can I create a custom JS function to copy plotly image to clipboard in JS without Shiny

Tags: javascript, plotly.js

I would like to implement a button in a plotly chart that copies the chart in png format to clipboard. I follow this answer to related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64721568/how-can-i-create-a-custom-js-function-to-copy-plotly-image-to-clipboard-in-r-shi/64722962#64722962) but I found some issues e.g. async await function and also blob() function not resolved. Can anyone give me insight to this issue?

[the button looks like this and clickable already](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYcP5.png)

Below is how the code look like right now.

```
name: 'CopyPNGToClipboard',
                title: 'CopyPNGToClipboard',
                icon: Plotly.Icons.disk,
                click: function (gd) {
                    
                        Plotly.Snapshot.toImage(gd, { format: "png" }).once( "success", function (url){
                            try {
                                debugger;
                              const data = fetch(url);
                              const blob = data.blob();
                              navigator.clipboard.write([
                                new ClipboardItem({
                                  [blob.type]: blob
                                })
                              ]);
                              console.log("Image copied.");
                            } catch (err) {
                              console.error(err.name, err.message);
                            }
                          }
                        );
                      }
```

**Edited Version**

```
{
                name: 'CopyToClipboard',
                title: 'Copy PNG To Clipboard',
                icon: Plotly.Icons.disk,
                click: function (gd) {
                    
                        Plotly.Snapshot.toImage(gd, { format: "png" }).once( "success", async function (url){
                            try {
                                debugger;
                              const data = await fetch(url);
                              const blob = await data.blob();
                              navigator.clipboard.write([
                                new ClipboardItem({
                                  [blob.type]: blob
                                })
                              ]);
                              console.log("Image copied.");
                            } catch (err) {
                              console.error(err.name, err.message);
                            }
                          }
                        );
                      }
            }
```

Comment: I just found the solution.. Async and await are necessary and I just ignore the unresolved feedback. Now the code works like a charm. Just copy paste it. See the edited version.

Comment: `"SyntaxError: unexpected token: ':'",`

Comment: @connexo Sorry I didn't intend to make it executable when clicking "run code snippet"