# How to export a R plotly graph in a server?

Tags: html, r, plotly

In R, I generated a plot using plotly and I want to export it as a .html file. I'm working in a server that has all the packages that I need, but somehow it doesn't behave like my laptop.
For example, in my machine just with

```
plot<-plot_ly(data = df, x = ~Vol1, y = ~Vol2, type = "scatter", mode = "markers", width = 900, height = 900,
       marker = list(symbol = "cross",size = 4, opacity = 0.5, color = "rgba(50,50,50,0.5)",alpha = I(0.8)))

save_html(plot, file = "plot.html")
```

everything is fine (it generates correctly the file "plot.html").
But for some reason in the server the output file is empty.
I tried playing around with other tools (i.e. saveWidget) but the result is the same.
Is there a different way to retrieve the plot? An HTML object would be excellent, but at this point even a .png is fine (orca doesn't work as well).

Comment: The "download" button of plotly doesn't work for the png?

Comment: Could you try [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64722962/1100107)? This is used to copy the plot to the clipboard, that you can then paste in a file.

Answer (score 1):

I usually go with `saveWidget`:

```
library(plotly)

fig <- plot_ly(x = 1:10, y = 1:10, type = "scatter", mode = "lines")

htmlwidgets::saveWidget(partial_bundle(fig), file = "plotly.html", selfcontained = TRUE)

utils::browseURL("plotly.html")
```

Are there any error messages on your server?