# How do I prevent shinyapp from being greyed out when killed

Tags: shiny

I use a shinyapp because I want to compare some plotly-graphs interactively (leaving one zoomed out while zooming into it at the same time. I have written a function that I can use to start such a shinyapp.

```
webGLApp <- function(p, n=2, height = "500px"){
  p <- plotly::toWebGL(p)
  ui <- shiny::fluidPage(
    shiny::tags$head(shiny::tags$style(type="text/css",
                         "body.disconnected {
                            background-color: inherit;
                            opacity: 1;
                          }"
    )),
    plotly::plotlyOutput("po1", height = height),
    plotly::plotlyOutput("po2", height = height),
    plotly::plotlyOutput("po3", height = height),
    plotly::plotlyOutput("po4", height = height),
  )
  
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    output$po1 <- plotly::renderPlotly(p) %>% shiny::bindCache("nothing")
    if (n>1) output$po2 <- plotly::renderPlotly(p) %>% shiny::bindCache("nothing")
    if (n>2) output$po3 <- plotly::renderPlotly(p) %>% shiny::bindCache("nothing")
    if (n>3) output$po4 <- plotly::renderPlotly(p) %>% shiny::bindCache("nothing")
  }
  
  shiny::runApp(shiny::shinyApp(ui, server, options = list(launch.browser = TRUE)))
}
```

Then my R code gets blocked while the shiny app is "online". If I kill the app then, I can use R again and also the plotly-plots stay reactive and everything is fine except that there is this gray layer above the app. Is there a way to prevent that?

I have found somewhere that setting the opacity to 1 or 0 could help, but this does not work the way I did it (as you can see once you try out my code).

What could I do instead?

Comment: If you aren't using any reactivity, why do you use shiny in the first place? You could render a HTML file via rmarkdown instead.

Comment: If there is a way to cache the plots, so I do not have to waste time doing the same calculation many times, I would be happy to do it that way. I just know how to use shiny quite well and have no experience with rmarkdown, so I would feel happy about this simple fix with removing the gray fog.

Comment: Via rmarkdown you can save standalone HTML files including interactive plotly charts. E.g. check [this](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/379188_3a2e3e316c604840a53c73151713d7a7.html). Also check [htmlwidgets::saveWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77110672/how-to-export-a-r-plotly-graph-in-a-server/77149880#77149880).